# Responsive positioning in center

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a full width background image with some content.
At the end I want to position my buttons in center (vertically and horizontally), but with `position:absolute`, that doesn't work. You can see it in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/hc8mmdL8/1/).

There is some code lines from my CSS

```
.buttons{
    position:relative;
}

.buttons .button-pos{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

And there is little scheme of that what I want.
[image]

Comment: Along with the @Johannes answer down below, you can take a look at [W3 Schools article about centering things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html), which will pretty much explain everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some solution by myself and it works now very well, I decided to center all my content, what was in the header. Only some little changes with screen sizes and it works well

```
#welcome-header .welcome-content{
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.buttons{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: but that's not centering, that's simply moving the `.buttons` divs bottom to 10% above its containers bottom. It still doesn't have a height. Try to rethink my answer again.

Comment: ?? `margin-top: 40px` doesn't give `.buttons` a height (i.e. still no centering)

Comment: @Johannes to me this solutions fits well, but I still want to center only buttons. I get all content centered and it looks good

Answer (score 2):

1.) Your `.buttons` div doesn't have a height, so first you need to define a height for it, otherwise there is no vertical centering possibility ( I made it 200px in the fiddle).

2.) To center `.button-pos` within `.buttons`, use

```
.button-pos {
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Luo1k7Lt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.buttons .button-pos { 
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

A simple IE hack is to add `display*: inline;` in that CSS rule